# Prove f'(a) is undefined when f(a) is undefined

Tags: limits, derivatives, proof-verification

I've been asking myself how to prove that if $f(a)$ is undefined for a function, then $f'(a)$ is also undefined. I can't seem to find a proof that is generalised for any $f$. Here is what I got:

**What I got**

Let $f$ be any function undefined at  $a$, then

$f(a)\  \nexists$

Now, $f'(a) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(a+h) + f(a)}h$

**Where I'm confused**

- Do I only need to know that $f(a)$ is undefined to complete the proof?
- Is there a better way to write it?

I'm sorry I know it's kind of a simple question but it's been bugging me for a while and I couldn't find the answer anywhere and I'm really trying to work on being more rigorous in my understanding of maths.

Thank you!

Comment: Well, **if** this limit exists, we call it the deriative of $f$ at $a$. Since $f(a)$ doesn't exist, the quotient $\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$ doesn't exist for any $h\in\mathbb R$...

Comment: @Ian Leclaire Think how a slope in a place could be even defined if that place does not exist.

Answer (score 3):

By definition, to prove that a function is differentiable at $x=a $, you need compute the limit
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac {f (a+h)-f (a)}{h} $$

For this, you should know the value of $f (a) $.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my rendition of the standard definition of the derivative, fully written out:

> Suppose that $f$ is a function whose values are real numbers, and which is defined at a real number $a$, and on a neighborhood of $a$. The derivative of $f$ at $a$, $f'(a)$, is the limit
>
> $$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a + h) + f(a)}{h},$$
>
> if this limit exists.

If we have a function $f$ which is *not* defined at a real number $a$ (in other words, $f(a)$ is not defined), then the conditions for the definition of $f'(a)$ are not satisfied, and so the definition of $f'(a)$ does not apply (in other words, $f'(a)$ is not defined).

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easier to think about this using contraposition. Your statement is equivalent to : If $f$ is differentiable at $a$, then $f$ is defined at $a$

To prove the equivalent statement, note that [differentiability implies continuity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1314630/differentiability-implies-continuity-a-question-about-the-proof), which implies $f$ being well-defined at point of differentiability.