# Does exist a non-continous function that can be differentiable?

Tags: calculus

Eg: f(0) doesn`t exist but f'(0) does exist.

Comment: No.  [Differentiability implies continuity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1314630/differentiability-implies-continuity-a-question-about-the-proof).

Comment: what about $f(x)=\frac xx$ for which $f'(0)=0$ but $f(0)$ is not defined

Comment: @WW1 so $f(x)=1$ if $x \neq 0$ and undefined otherwise, hence $f'(0)=\lim_{h \to 0} h^{-1}[f(0+h)-f(0)]$ is undefined since $f(0)$ is undefined...

Comment: non-continuity at 0 is an entirely different notion than non-definedness at 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No: differentiability implies continuity.

Comment: oh ok,thanks :)