# Differentiability and Uniform Continuity Proof

Tags: real-analysis

How would I prove the following without using the Mean Value thm?

If f is differentiable on [a,b], then f is uniformly continuous on [a,b].

Likewise, for the following: If f is differentiable on (a,b) and f(a)=f(b)=0, then f is uniformly continuous on [a,b]. Would this be the same proof as above since the two endpoints are zero, thus closed? Or is this in fact false?

Comment: In fact, you only need $f$ to be continuous on $[a, b]$ in the first case. For the second case, consider a function, $f$, on $[0,1]$ such that we define $f(0) = f(1) = 0$, and $f(x) = \frac1x$ for $x \in (0,1)$.

Comment: @JohnDon So f clearly cannot include zero, thus it is differentiable on (0,1)?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean. The function that I defined for the second case is a counterexample to the claim - can you check that: a) it is zero at the endpoints,  b) it is differentiable on (0,1),  c) it is not uniformly continuous on [0,1] (in fact it is not even continuous on [0,1]).

Comment: Oh ok I see, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint, $[a,b]$ is what we call a compact (and this is actually true for any compact set), i.e. closed and bounded in Euclidean space.

Claim: Continuous functions on compacts are uniformly continuous.

To prove this, use a contradiction argument, assume that $f$ not uniformly continuous: you have sequences $x_n,y_n$ with $|x_n-y_n|\to 0$ but $|f(x_n)-f(y_n)|\geq \epsilon$. Where does this lead you in combination with Bolzano-Weierstrass?

Comment: If you are going to mention compactness, it may be worth mentioning why the proof is true for general compact sets. As it stands, the compactness comment seems a bit ad-hoc - the only key statement is that Bolzano-Weierstrass applies to closed-bounded sets in Euclidean space.

Comment: Fair enough, I was hinting at that but I see that it might be confusing as it stands.

Comment: @Winston well I know BWT says every bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence, but I'm not sure how that connects to differentiability ?

Comment: You don't need differentiability other than that it implies continuity, which is enough. Apply BW to the sequences I gave you with this in mind.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1314630/differentiability-implies-continuity-a-question-about-the-proof shows that continuity is implied by differentiability without MWT