# Does mean-square differentiability imply mean-square continuity?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

We say that a random process $X_t$ is mean-square differentiable at time $t_0$ if there is a random process $X_{t_0}'$ such that 
$$\lim_{t\to t_0} \mathbb{E}\Big[\big(X_{t_0}' - \frac{X_t - X_{t_0}}{t-t_0}\big)^2\Big]=0$$
We say that a random process $X_t$ is mean-square continuous at time $t_0$ if 
$$\lim_{t\to t_0} \mathbb{E}\big[(X_{t} - X_{t_0})^2\big]=0$$

From calculus, we know that [differentiability implies continuity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1314630/differentiability-implies-continuity-a-question-about-the-proof). Does the same statement hold in stochastic calculus?

More formally, suppose a process is mean-square differentiable for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$. Is this process mean-square continuous for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's true.

Using the elementary inequality $$(x+y)^2 \leq 2x^2+2y^2, \qquad x,y \in \mathbb{R}$$ we find

$$\begin{align*} (X_t-X_{t_0})^2 &= (t-t_0)^2 \left( \frac{X_t-X_{t_0}}{t-t_0} - X_{t_0}' + X_{t_0}' \right)^2 \\ &\leq 2 (t-t_0)^2 \left( \frac{X_t-X_{t_0}}{t-t_0}-X_{t_0}' \right)^2 + 2(t-t_0)^2 (X_{t_0}')^2. \end{align*}$$

Taking expectations on both sides we get

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{E}((X_t-X_{t_0})^2) &\leq 2(t-t_0)^2 \underbrace{\mathbb{E} \left[ \left( \frac{X_t-X_{t_0}}{t-t_0}-X_{t_0}' \right)^2 \right]}_{\xrightarrow[]{t \to t_0} 0} + 2 \underbrace{(t-t_0)^2}_{\xrightarrow[]{t \to t_0} 0} \mathbb{E}((X_{t_0}')^2) \\ &\xrightarrow[]{t \to t_0} 0. \end{align*}$$

Comment: Thank you! One note: from this proof, it looks like this should be true only when $X_{t_0}'$ is second order, since we require that $\mathbb{E}[(X_{t_0}')^2]$ be finite. So this would apply when $X_t$ is WSS, but may not work otherwise.

Comment: @sharkbait Actually $\mathbb{E}((X_{t_0}')^2)<\infty$ follows from $$\mathbb{E} \left[ \left( \frac{X_t-X_{t_0}}{t-t_0} - X_{t_0}' \right)^2 \right]< \infty$$ for $t$ close to $t_0$ and the fact that $(X_t)_t$ is square-integrable.