# Differentiability of a non-continuous function

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, continuity

So the question that comes to my mind is  does differentiability require continuity? I have read it many a times but what I think of it like this, lets say a piecewise function as below is defined
$$f(x) =\begin{cases} x^2 & x \leq 0 \\[2ex]\ x^2-1 & x \gt \mathbb 0 \end{cases}$$

Now as $x\rightarrow0$ the right hand derivative approaches zero and so does the left hand derivative.
So apparently the derivative should exit at all points, even though it isn't continuous. Am I somehow wrong here? I recently completed my school so an answer at that level would be really helpful.

Comment: Your function $f$ is **not** differentiable at $x=0$.

Comment: The right hand derivative does not exist:  $f(0) = 0$ but for positive $h$, $  f(0+h) $ is close to $-1$ so by definition, there is no right derivative.  $f$ cannot simultaneously be $0$ and $-1$ at $x=0$.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1314630/42969.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The situation you have here is one where the derivative doesn't exist at $x=0$, but the derivative function can be continuously extended to $x=0$. This continuous extension is no longer the derivative function though!

What you need to realize is that at it's core, the derivative is an object which can exist at every point separately. We can use the separate derivatives at all these points to construct another function, the derivative function, whose behavior is not predetermined at first glance. It could have holes, horrible discontinuities, edges, all kinds of erratic behavior. Some cool theorems (Darboux's theorem, for instance) do end up restricting it's possible behavior, but that's not important right now. The point is that the way the derivative function behaves at certain points doesn't tell us anything about how it behaves elsewhere, unless you manage to find one of those cool theorems. And there's no theorem that says: "if the derivative function has a removable hole, then the original function is actually differentiable at the hole".

Instead, you should think about what it means to be differentiable at a point. It just means that there's a unique tangent line applicable to the function's graph at that point. Drawing your function, you'll quickly see that this is not the case, so it's not differentiable at $x=0$.

Comment: That extension thing I didn't get it, is it like what we do when we have a removable discontinuity in a function?And I still don't get why we can't draw a tangent at x=0? You said that the tangent needs to be unique, I don't see why isn't it if it is the reason for which the function isn't differentiable at x=0.

Comment: Look at the graph: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ufxpigiesm .
How would you draw a tangent at the jump discontinuity?

Comment: So it's basically for the slope to be defined the function needs to be continuous at least very near to that point?

Comment: It only needs to be continuous at the point. Everywhere else it's allowed to be discontinuous.

Answer (score 0):

Know your definitions:

$f$ is *continuous* at $x_0$ if $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=f(x_0)$

$f$ is *differentiable* at $x_0$ if $f'(x_0)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}$ exists.

If $f$ is *discontinuous*, $\lim_{h\to 0}f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)\neq 0$, and so $f$ is *not differentiable* (suppose the difference is $a$, then we get $f'(x_0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac ah$ which doesn't exist).

In general, differentiability requires continuity, but isn't always implied by it.