# Why is it necessary for $f(x)$ to be continuous at $x=a$ for $f'(a)$ to be defined?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, derivatives, continuity

Consider a function $f(x)=x^2-x$ when $0\leq x<1$
and $f(x)=2/3 x^3-4x^2+7x-8/3$  when $1\leq x<3$.

We had to check differentiability at $x=1$. So, we could either do this the limit way, or just differentiate both functions and see if they were continuous at $x=1$. By the second method, I got that both functions' differentiations were continuous at $x=1$, so $f$ is differentiable at $x=1$. However, the answer given is that $f$ is not differentiable at $x=1$, because $f(x)$ is not continuous at $x=1$.

So, why is that a necessity?

Comment: Differentiability at a point *implies* continuity at that point, see for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1314630/42969. – Your argument that $f$ is differentiable at $x=1$ because it is differentiable for $x < 1$ and for $x> 1$ and the  left and right derivatives have the same limit at $x=1$ is wrong.

Comment: Let $f'(a)$ exists, then $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=\lim_{x\to a} (\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}(x-a)+f(a))=f'(a)\lim_{x\to a}(x-a)+f(a)=f(a)$ which is equivalent to continuity of $f(x)$ at $x=a$.

Comment: I recommend graphing the functions on their intervals, because the limits from the left and right differ.  A real analysis theorem states that $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = L \iff \lim_{x \to a+} f(x) = L \ and \ \lim_{x \to a-} f(x) = L$. The definition of continuity implies that for each  $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists \delta$ such that $|f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon$ whenever $|x - a| < \delta$.

Answer (score 1):

A function has to be continuous to be differentiable. Your second method is wrong. The left function is not defined at $x=1$ so how to have a slope?